# Java SE Look&Feel не может найти класс Nimbus

Tags: java

Пользуюсь NetBeans 8.1 Java 1.8 , в режиме визуального редактора JFrame устанавливаю стиль Nimbus - работает прекрасно, использую код генерируемый этим редактором и создаю простой класс(все тот же extended JFrame) в проекте, в случаи одиночного запуска именно этого класса - стиль сохраняется однако:

```
 if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                               UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());                                
                               break;
                       }else {System.out.println("Nimbus not found >"+UIManager.getLookAndFeel());}
                   }
```

Вывод: Nimbus not found >[The Java(tm) Look and Feel - javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel]
То есть стиль установился, однако не был найден?
Если же запускать фрейм вызовом из основного проекта, через :

```
new GUI().setVisible(true);
```

Возвращает уже в метал стиле... Есть подозрение что в случаи наличия более одного фрейма в проекте, стиль надо задавать как-то глобально, или допустим все зависит от иерархии вызовов и стиль определяется по предыдущему фрейму.
Сам проект пока прост : 
Main class
 -> 
Авторизация
(Лучше бы использовать диалоговое окно, знаю... но пока есть необходимость в фрейме) 
-> 
GUI (фрейм).

Главный вопрос как установить Nimbus на весь проект?

Comment: Удивительно, но решил проблему, скорее всего причиной ее появления является мое решение переноса кода с редактора (JFrame) в обычный Java clаss, возможно в ваших глазах оно выглядит неадекватно, но альтернатив для себя пока не нашел, визуальный редактор моего IDE неудобен для правок руками, и код который он генерирует для меня слишком громоздкий поэтому приходиться много править руками.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В конструкторе созданного класса GUI:

```
    public GUI() {
    setLaF();
   // initComponents();
}
```

Сам сэттер для стиля:

```
    private void setLaF() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable( ) {
    public void run( ) {
            //set L&F
            try {
                   for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                       if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                               UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                               break;
                       }
                   }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                // If Nimbus is not available, you can set the GUI to another look and feel.
                 e.printStackTrace();
                }
        //create UI and components here
   System.out.println("Nimbus not found >"+UIManager.getLookAndFeel());
   initComponents();
    }
});
}
```

Все работает прекрасно, но все же если у кого либо будут дельные мысли, идеи или замечания не откажусь выслушать.